# getResourceAsStrem with maven structure

Tags: java, maven, properties, intellij-idea

I have the following maven project structure:

```
src
--main
----java
------de
--------mxcd
--------foodster
----------Test.java
----------hans.txt
```

Using this code I get a NullPointerException

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputStream ins = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("hans.txt");
        Properties p = new Properties();

        try
        {
            p.load(ins);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(p.getProperty("100"));
    }
}
```

This doesn't happen when I change my project structure to

```
src
--de
----mxcd
------foodster
--------Test.java
--------hans.txt
```

Why is this so? As far as I know, getResourceAsStream() looks for the file relative to the classes positition, so it shouldn't make a difference wheather I am using /src/de/mxcd... or src/main/java/de/mxcd...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file should be in `src/main/resources`, not `src/main/java`. Only `.java` files from `src/main/java` will end up (compiled) in the target classpath, whereas files in `src/main/resources` will be copied as-is.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the answer by Joe is correct. Important is, that in the src/main/resources folder, the same folder structure as in the src/main/java folder is required.

This means if you want to access a file with getResource and the class you are calling it with is located under /src/main/java/de/mxcd/util/ then your file has to be under /src/main/resources/de/mxcd/util

When using intelliJ it is critical to create every folder of this structure on its own and not by entering de.mxcd.util as new folder name under resoucres (what would work if you would create a new package)